# Шкала Scale и её параметры

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Может кто-нибудь объяснить за что отвечает каждая строчка кода шкалы, как её использовать и как написать её минимумом кода.
Вот код найденный на pythonworld.ru, так ничего и не объяснил.

```
class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Scale")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")        

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        scale = Scale(self, from_=0, to=100, 
            command=self.onScale)
        scale.pack(side=LEFT, padx=15)

        self.var = IntVar()
        self.label = Label(self, text=0, textvariable=self.var)        
        self.label.pack(side=LEFT)

    def onScale(self, val):
        v = int(float(val))
        self.var.set(v)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    ex = Example(root)
    root.geometry("250x100+300+300")
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ну, во-первых я бы не сказал что это минимум кода (независимо от того, что думает об этом автор pythonworld). Во-вторых, неплохо бы указать конкретно адрес страницы, откуда взят код. В-третьих что именно вам не понятно, что конкретно вы хотите получить?

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/tkinter-widgets-example -взят код. Мне непонятно, за что отвечают строки кода и как сделать переменную, зависимую от значения шкалы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно минимальный пример (который ничего не делает, только создает ползунок в окне):

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

scale = ttk.Scale(root)
scale.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Печать значения в консоль при перемещении движка:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def on_scroll(val):
    print(val)

scale = ttk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, command=on_scroll)
scale.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Получение значения в произвольный момент (при нажатии кнопки) через привязанную переменную:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

scale_var = tk.IntVar()
scale = ttk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, variable=scale_var)
scale.pack()

def on_button_press():
    print(scale_var.get())

button = ttk.Button(text="Press me", command=on_button_press)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```